# SqlServerCE Select statement Native Exception

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-mobile

WinMobile 6.1 Prof. CE OS 5.2.20269 SqlserverCE 3.5. Problem solid when debugging and also when deployed.

Select count(*) from table and you get a valid result and code flows as expected.

Select field name from table and the executereader throws a native exception. i.e. The error is outside of the executing code and the 'catch' statement does not execute.

Delving into the error Details on the mobile device shows the erroring dll is sqlceqp35.dll at SqlCeDataReader.FillMetaData (which is called from initializeDataReader)

Other answers have indicated to use 
sqlce.repl.ppc.wce4.armv4.CAB and friends on the device. I installed these taking the default 'device' option but it has made no difference.

WinMobile experience is minimal so maybe I am missing something simple.

Funnily enough I write to the database upstream no problem.

The connection string  is:

```
 private const string MsConn = @"Data Source=Program Files\Inspector\Inspector.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Dataclass function follows:

```
public int GetLogonId()
    {
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(MsConn);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCeCommand cmdSelect = conn.CreateCommand();
        SqlCeDataReader r = null;
        try
        {
            const string sqlSelect = "select inspector from Inspector"; 
            //const string sqlSelect = "Select count(*) from Inspector"; This works
            cmdSelect.CommandText = sqlSelect;
            //cmdSelect.Prepare();
             r = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();//Native error here
            return r.Read() ? r.GetInt32(0) : 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("GetLogonId " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            cmdSelect.Dispose();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the column is `inspector` and not `Inspector`? (Could be cAsE SenSiTIvE - not familiar enough with CE to know for sure if this is an issue.)

Comment: Hi Aaron, shouldn't be case sensitive but I have double checked and the column name  is 'inspector' thanks Bob

Comment: Object names in CE are never case sensitive. Have you tried [Inspector] ?

Comment: tried [inspector]. Beginning to think it is something quirky about versions and the Mobile Device type. The upstream write makes use of the field names happily. Inspection of the SDF shows the write was successful. And just to make it completely baffling I put the field name in a where clause for the select count(*) statement and it still works. So the problem is specific to the Select clause. Methinks the sdf is going in the bin and I'll use xml files to hold the data.

Comment: Built a simple app that only does the database thing. It works on the emulator and fails on the mobile device so I am deploying wrong file versions or something. (Dev Environment is VS2008 sitting on Winserver 2008R2 64 bit). I'll chase it down. Thanks to all commentors.

Comment: Turned out to be the Mobile Device. Did a hardware reset of device and away it went. Bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error in my smart device application. Please visit the following  [link](http://www.wiki-errors.com/wiki-errors.php?wiki=0xc0000005)

You can hard reset/cold boot your device and reinstall the sql ce cab files:

1. sqlce.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB
2. sqlce.repl.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB
3. sqlce.dev.ENU.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB